# Resharper code cleanup and Azure Function method signatures

Tags: c#, resharper

I'd like R# 2017.3.3 not to introduce newlines for my Azure function method signatures when I run code cleanup. Expected:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
```

how it formats on built-in full cleanup

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]
                                              HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
```

I've tried various combinations of wrap at line length, attribute wrapping, and general C# line breaks but can't seem to find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try increasing the value of `Place attribute section list on separate line if it is longer than` property here `ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Line Breaks and Wrapping | Arrangement of Attributes`

Comment: That worked, thank you. I am surprised that the default value of 0 doesn't honor the wrap long lines options from General as the right margin option does

Comment: "0" value in "Place attribute section list on separate line if it is longer than" property tells ReSharper to always place the code after an attribute on a new line. And yes, it does not depend on Wrap Long Line option.